# Como especificar uma propriedade CSS em um único elemento para uma classe que se repete?

Tags: html, css

Tenho um site Wordpress. No tema, preciso personalizar o `height` de uma única `div` da classe `image_wrapper`, porém quando faço a alteração, isso reflete nas outras `divs` da mesma classe espalhadas pelo tema.

Como posso definir o `height` nesse caso, sem que as demais `divs` sofram a alteração?

A `div` que preciso personalizar está contida nesta outra:

```
<div class="image_frame scale-with-grid product-loop-thumb">
    <div class="image_wrapper">
        <a href=""></a>
    </div>
</div>

div.image_wrapper {
  height: 192px; }
```

Quando uso o CSS acima, outras `divs` de mesma classe são alteradas, como a seguinte:

```
<div class="image_wrapper"><img class="scale-with-grid" src="" alt=""></div>
```

Como é possível resolver? Não consegui usar a especificidade nesse caso.

Comment: Vc consegue alterar essa div específica?

Comment: Você terá que criar um seletor único para este elemento. Se tiver algum elemento pai que define um `id` facilitará bastante. Você pode utilizar o inspetor do navegador para te auxiliar neste processo: pressione o botão direito do mouse sobre o elemento desejado e acesse "Inspecionar Elemento", certifique-se que o elemento correto está devidamente selecionado pelo inspetor e veja o seletor inteiro na barra bem abaixo. Mas se editar o HTML as coisas ficam bem mais fáceis.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você tem acesso ao código dessa `div`, pode adicionar uma outra classe própria para ela. Neste caso, só ela será alterada mantendo o estilo que já foi definido em `.image_wrapper`:

```
div.image_wrapper.outraclasse {
  height: 192px;
}

<div class="image_wrapper outraclasse"><img class="scale-with-grid" src="" alt=""></div>
```

**Exemplo:**

```css
div.image_wrapper.outraclasse {
  height: 192px;
}

.image_wrapper{
   display: block; width: 400px; height: 20px; background: red; margin: 5px 0
}
```

```html
<div class="image_wrapper"><img class="scale-with-grid" src="" alt="">
   Esta div é igual as outras
</div>
<div class="image_wrapper outraclasse"><img class="scale-with-grid" src="" alt="">
   Esta div é igual as outras mas tem uma alteração na altura
</div>
<div class="image_wrapper"><img class="scale-with-grid" src="" alt="">
   Esta div é igual as outras
</div>
```

Comment: Localizei a DIV em questão e adicionei outra classe à classe image_wrapper, assim como explicou. Muito obrigado, resolvido!

Comment: @Fernando Fico contente em ter ajudado. Considere marcar ✓ na resposta. Abs!